# Prefilling HTML fields in IE7 & IE8

Tags: php, html

Just had a problem reported about a date of birth sign up form on our website.  The form is prefilled with sample values.  This works fine in Firefox, Chrome (and to an extent IE9), but not IE7 or IE8.  I can tab into the fields but not click into them.  It seems that the prefilled values are getting in the way of being able to select the box (in IE9 I can only click to select the input field if I click just in front of the value).

```
<div class="DobBack">
    <input name="dobD" id="dobD" type="text" value="" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" />
    <div class="abInputText">DD</div>
</div>

<div class="abDobBack">
    <input name="dobM" id="dobM" type="text" value="" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=2 />
    <div class="abInputText">MM</div>
</div>

<div class="abDobBack">
    <input name="dobY" id="dobY" type="text" value="" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=4 />
    <div class="abInputText">YYYY</div>
</div> ​
```

Is this a problem with the code or with IE or both?  No idea how long the problem has been going on, there's been no updates for months, but just suddenly getting the questions.

Comment: What are the varialbes like '.$dobD.' supposed to be? JavaScript variables?

Comment: Sorry, these are php Variables - trimmed the code a bit to much for brevity I think

Comment: Life is a lot easier when you use a templating engine: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/

Comment: If ONLY I had even the slightest say in how we do things here...:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume this is PHP.

```
  <div class="DobBack">
        <input name="dobD" id="dobD" type="text" value="<?php echo $dobD ?>" onfocus="value=\'\'" class="ab abReq abDob abNum"></input>
        <div class="abInputText">DD</div>
    </div>

    <div class="abDobBack">
        <input name="dobM" id="dobM" type="text" value="<?php echo $dobM ?>'" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=2 />
        <div class="abInputText">MM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="abDobBack">
        <input name="dobY" id="dobY" type="text" value="<?php echo $dobY ?>" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=4 />
        <div class="abInputText">YYYY</div>
    </div>
```

If not, what is $dobM, what language is this, where is $dobM defined, can you post full code?

#### Part 2

```
$html='<div class="DobBack">
    <input name="dobD" id="dobD" type="text" value="'.$dobD.'" onfocus="value=\'\'" class="ab abReq abDob abNum"></input>
    <div class="abInputText">DD</div>
</div>

<div class="abDobBack">
    <input name="dobM" id="dobM" type="text" value="'.$dobM.'" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=2 />
    <div class="abInputText">MM</div>
</div>

<div class="abDobBack">
    <input name="dobY" id="dobY" type="text" value="'.$dobY.'" class="ab abReq abDob abNum" maxlength=4 />
    <div class="abInputText">YYYY</div>
</div> ​';
```

It should look like that.

Go to view source to see if the value shows up. you should see  if ($dobY == 1985)

The other potential issue is the onfocus event. try `onFocus="this.value=''; return false;"`

Comment: You are correct, it's PHP, will attempt to add the code to the question

Comment: The <?php echo ?> is what makes it work. I just did that quickly, you may need to use <?php echo $dobM; ?> If that doesn't work please post code.

Comment: We're doing it the other way round - the html is built inside a PHP block. My fault for cutting the code segment: consider the html surround by <?php $html = [...] ?>.  The html is assigned to a variable and displayed later.

Comment: Consolidated several comments into post. See post

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have edited the code in the original question as having tested without it, I can see the php code actually has no bearing on problem and just confuses the issue.  Without anything in the value field the prepopulation problem still exists in IE.

Comment: Is this site online anywhere? It may be due to one of the CSS classes (ab abReq abDob abNum).